# VS2010 Connection Dialog GAC Error in Windows XP

Tags: sql-server, database-connection, windows-xp-sp3

All,

I am using the VS2010 database connection dialog that Microsoft have released ([download from here](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/Connection)). I am using this without any problems on Windows 7. However, when I install the application on Windows XP (using the 'Publish' option in VS2010) I get the following error

[image: Error upon installation]

Using NSIS, the application installs but upon trying to launch the VS2010 dialog I get the following error

[image: Runtime Error]

Clearly the first error is telling me what the problem is, but as I have never come across this before I am not sure what I can do to address/fix it. Could this be associated with not using the manifest correctly?

As always any help is most appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that in your Windows XP is missing the library for Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5 
You could download the bits from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=5821)